# Grabbing key value from a mysql query

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

I thought this was quite basic but for some reason I can't figure it out.

I have this query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users.Information LIMIT 0,1");
```

To grab the data (such as firstName, lastName), I use this snippet of code

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>

    <?php foreach($row as $key=>$value) {   
        echo $value; 
    } ?> 

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

which correctly prints everything I want.

Now in a separate table, I want to have it such that I will print the individual values separately. I thought this was quite simple like

first name:

however, this does not work. If I just do $value, of course this makes sense, but it prints the last value in the array.

How do I grab individual values? Do I just parse $value into different values, or is there an easier way?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = array() ; //Create a storage, so you can access it later.

<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
    $data[] = $row ; //Add the value to storage.
    <?php foreach($row as $key=>$value) {   
        echo $value; 
    } ?> 

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

We are ready. We have `$data` array with all rows. Now you can manipulate it, access elements, pass somewhere.

```
$data[0] ; //Access the first element

echo $data[0]['FirstName'] ; //Print first name of the first row.
```